# Azure Neo4J Will Not Deploy

Tags: azure, neo4j

I'm trying to deploy a neo4j Enterprise Cluster using the Azure Portal GUI. I'm just doing a vanilla install. When I get to the last step, the error reads:

```
InvalidContentLink

Unable to download deployment content from 'https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/neo4j.neo4j-enterprise-editionha.1.0.10/Artifacts/clusterTemplate.json'. The tracking Id is '99f19bbe-f9f8-4e04-91b7-7aa58a82922f'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
Basics
Subscription
Not free trial
Resource group
neo4j
Location
(US) West US 2
Admin Account Name
reallyHardToGuess
Password
****************
Neo4j Settings
Neo4j Version
Neo4j 3.1
Neo4j password
****************
SSL Certificate
-
SSL Private Key
-
Neo Cluster Name
neo
Number of VMs
3
Size of each VM
Standard D4 v2
Virtual network for the Cluster
neo-vnet-01
Subnet for Cluster VMs
clusterSubnet
Subnet for Cluster VMs address prefix
10.0.0.0/24
Public IP address
NeoIP001
None
-
```

The URL for the deployment content does not resolve:
[image]

I've tried all versions of neo4j and a bunch of different VM choices. Same result. Please advise.

EDIT: 2 weeks later...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. I''m surprised that a blocking issue in Azure doesn't get more attention. I'm literally unable to deploy a service here!

Comment: HELLO!?! I'm trying to stand up a Neo4J Azure instance a couple weeks later, same issue. Whats the deal?

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being that Azure was showing an outdated Neo4J option ("Enterprise Edition"). One must select "Casaul Cluster" to pass validation:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Azure instance of "Enterprise Edition VM" is currently invalid. Only option is to choose Causal Cluster or (potentially) deploy Enterprise Edition VM via this method on Medium (https://medium.com/neo4j/how-to-automate-neo4j-deploys-on-azure-d1eaeb15b70a)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old template that is no longer supported.  The correct one is here:  https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/neo4j.neo4j-enterprise-causal-cluster?tab=Overview

Notice that you are attempting to launch Neo4j version 3.1, which is probably about 2 years old.  The current stable version is 3.5 with 4.0 soon available.

Use the updated version.

Comment: Interesting. Because I'm literally clicking my way through the Azure GUI using the prompts. Even selecting "Use latest version". Also, I don't want a Causal Cluster, but rather the Enterprise Version.